# MIssing icon file in xcodeproj in Yosemite

Tags: ios, xcode, icons, osx-yosemite, xcode-project

i have some interesting problem with my Xcode 6.1.1 Blue icon like on xcodeproj files was dissapeared, i already installed new version thousand times but it's not solution. Also i tried to find some topics about it but really nothing!

[image]

Comment: I'm interested in this too, in my case also some .h files are showing blank documents as icons, while others .h files don't, even when they are in the same folder, did you solve this problem?

Comment: Yes but it's not good choose...so i reinstalled my os and download xcode again...

Comment: I'll try reinstalling Xcode, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recently ran into this.

Select the ".xcodeproj" icon in the Finder and "Get Info"

Then left click or command and drag the blank file to the top left xcode file.  The blank file will be replaced with the correct artwork

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The fact you're not seeing an icon is merely cosmetic and not a performance issue.

It may be that you have multiple copies of Xcode on your machine.  You should delete all copies of Xcode EXCEPT the copies you want to continue using.

And to make the icon appear again, select the ".xcodeproj" icon in the Finder and do a "Get Info" (in Finder, you'll find that choice under the "File" menu).

When the Get Info panel is open, you can select "Open With" and choose the version of Xcode you want to associate the project with, like this:

[image: Use Get Info to select "Open With"]

Comment: so the icon is still blank?  also, when double clicking the Xcode project icon, does it open Xcode?